# Excel IF & AND formula if blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have this formula and its working great, but when all columns blank the formula shows "Requires
Improvement" . I need if all columns blank the result here it should be blank

=IF(AND(AD15>AD16,AD15>AD17),"Effective",IF(AND(AD16>=AD15,AD16>=AD17),"Requires
Improvement",IF(AND(AD17>AD15,AD17>AD16),"Requires Immediate Attention")))

Comment: Nest what you have in the `FALSE` argument of another `IF` statement and place an empty string in the `TRUE` argument. For the comparison, use your same approach using `AND()` but compare cells to an empty string: `""`.

Comment: Will your logic ever get to the 3rd test?

Answer (score 0):

If your current formula works fine then just replace `Requires Improvement` with empty string. Try-

```
=IF(AND(AD15>AD16,AD15>AD17),"Effective",IF(AND(AD16>=AD15,AD16>=AD17),"",IF(AND(AD17>AD15,AD17>AD16),"Requires Immediate Attention")))
```

Comment: If I replace "Requires Improvement" with empty string then will not working if the result should be "Requires Improvement"

Answer (score 0):

Using `IFS()` and handling unanticipated situations:

`=IFS(AND(AD15="",AD16="",AD17=""),"",AND(AD15>AD16,AD15>AD17),"Effective",AND(AD16>=AD15,AD16>=AD17),"Requires Improvement",AND(AD17>AD15,AD17>AD16),"Requires Immediate Attention",TRUE,"Other Situation")`

Comment: Im using excel 2016 and there in no IFS()