# Excel formula need to be blank if there are no choice

Tags: excel, if-statement, count

As picture below  in column "C" I have 6 variables consisting of one of the 3 choices  (Effective, Requires Improvement, Requires Immediate Attention). and in column "E" I have formula to count how many times each choice is repeated. Next in column "G" I have a formula that shows if any of the three choices repeats more than the rest, the result is the most frequent, and if the three choices are equal then the result "Requires improvement" .

The formula works great but if results are 0 in column "E" then result in column "G" shows "Requires Improvement" but I need it to be blank because in column 'C' is not selected.
Formula in column "G" IF(AND(F5>F6,F5>F7),"Effective",IF(AND(F6>=F5,F6>=F7),"Requires Improvement",IF(AND(F7>F5,F7>F6),"Requires Immediate Attention")))[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel IF & AND formula if blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70664909/excel-if-and-formula-if-blank)

Comment: No, my question has not been answered

Comment: Not a very helpful response. Why didn't you respond to the answers to your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

> need to be blank if there are no choice

```
=IF(a1=1,"OK","")
```

Please share if it works/not.